# Unknown Fruit Vine (reddish purple fruit, hollow inside)

Tags: identification, vines

There's this mysterious vine growing at my wife's grandfather's home that I can't identify. Its tall enough to have climbed up the fence and made its way over. I've included various images taken of the plant. The fruit is like a reddish purple fig/guava looking thing. When I cut it open there's no real scent on it, at least nothing that's pleasing and desirable for triggering an eating reflex.

What could this strange vine be?

[image: fruit and vine with leaves]

[image: closeup of fruit on vine]

[image: another closeup of fruit on vine]

[image: showing what look like immature buds]

[image: detailing vine/branch structure]

[image: showing closeup of fruit cut open]

Comment: Could it be passiflora edulis, or her cousin?

Comment: Looks like [purple figs](https://www.starkbros.com/growing-guide/article/how-to-tell-when-figs-are-ripe), however the form of the leafs don't match.

Comment: It may be a [strangler fig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus_aurea) or [shortleaf fig](http://www.southfloridatrees.org/?page_id=627), does you grandpa in law live in Florida?

Comment: looks like some sort of fig

Comment: agree - looks like some sort of fig.

Answer (score 2):

Got some feedback, my wife's aunt claims its a `fig vine`, which online comes up as `creeping fig vine`. Check out this page linked below, I believe the fruit they image matches up pretty closely.

[Ficus pumila Facts: Growing the Creeping Fig Vine](http://www.botanical-journeys-plant-guides.com/ficus-pumila.html).

The image they link looks like a decent match, but when you search more broadly online for `creeping fig vine fruit` the bulk of the images seem like a different variety so I'm not 100% on this identification.